# SQL query disables calendar

Tags: javascript, php, sql, calendar

I have a JavaScript calendar

```
<input type="text" size="8" id="date"  name="calendar[]" />
```

When I input the following php it disables the calendar.

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from products where id='maui'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

but if I input the php without the "where clause" it works:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from products");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

What are some options for a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine there is either a syntax error in you query, or the `id` does not exist and therefore no results are returned. So always check the status of a database access call

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from products where id='maui'");
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if ( mysql_num_rows() == 0 ) {
    echo 'No results returned';
    exit;
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

> Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
>   [and here is some help to decide which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)